# How to see that $e^{x(1+x/3)} \le (1+x)^{(1+x)}$ for very small x>0?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am reading a research paper and one of the calculation states that

> $e^{x(1+x/3)} \le (1+x)^{(1+x)}$ for very small x>0.

Is this true? How to prove it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Depends what you know. If you know the Taylor expansion of the logarithm, looking at $x(1+x/3) \leqslant (1+x)\log (1+x)$ helps.

Comment: Take $\ln$ of both sides.

Comment: I think I see. Does this mean that it should be true even if I replace 3 by any fixed constant more than 2?

Comment: @eig That's right.

Comment: what do you mean with very small?

Comment: You may convince yourself by taking $\lim{x\rightarrow 0} $ on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the equivalent $$f(x) = \log(1+x) - \frac{x}{1+x}\left(1+\frac{x}k\right) \ge 0$$

Now $f'(x) = \dfrac{x(k-2-x)}{(1+x)^2}$, so for any $k> 2$, the numerator remains positive for $0< x< k-2$ and $f(0)=0$, so the inequality holds for some nbd to the right of $0$.

Comment: How would you treat left side of $0$? It should hold as well.

Comment: @Ennar the same logic works, to the left of $0$, one gets $f'(x)$ is negative, so $f(x)> 0$ for all negative $x$, for which $\log(1+x)$ is defined...

Comment: Oh, yeah... somehow, I thought negative derivative would be problem, should have sketched it earlier. I've been messing with Taylor approximations and it works very easily for positive $x$'s, but I can't get them to work for negative ones. Anyway, this is very nice answer, +1. EDIT: Oh, well, just made it work, but doesn't seem worthwhile to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$h(x)=\frac{(1+x)^{(1+x)}}{e^{x(1+x/3)}}$$
We have:
$$h(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)}, \ \ x\rightarrow0$$
and $e^{x^2/6}\geq 1$. See figure:

[image]